# sign of roots of a quadratic equation with complex coefficients.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Consider $x^2+ax+b=0$, where $x$ is the variable and $a,b$ are complex coefficients. Is there any condition on $a$ and $b$ which makes sure the roots of the equation have negative real parts?

Comment: A *necessary* condition is $\Re a>0$, a *sufficient* condition is $4|b|<(\Re a)^2$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: How did you obtain this inequalities? Here I have a similler question. Can you help me to solve it? Thank you. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/985518/question-about-quadratic-equation-of-complex-coefficients

Comment: @Nilan $-a$ is the sum of the two roots, hence $\Re a>0$ is necessary.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: I got that. How did you get the sufficient condition?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\,z_1:=a+bi\,,\,z_2:=c+di\in\Bbb C\,$ be the two roots, then using Viete's formulae:

$$ac-bd+(ad+bc)i=z_1z_2=b:=x+yi$$

$$a+c+(b+d)i=z_1+z_2=-a:=-p-qi$$

Now compare real and imaginary parts in the two expressions above.