# d/g is a real number if the roots of the equation x^2 + dx + g^2 = 0 have the same absolute value?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

$d$ and $g$ are complex numbers and $g$ is not eqaul to $0$. Prove that if the roots of the equation $$x^2 + dx + g^2 = 0$$ have the same absolute value, then $d/g$ is a real number.

I tried to solve the problem by finding the roots and then transforming the results into the form of $d/g$. But it seems that I am going in the wrong direction.

Could somebody tell as to how the problem could be solved?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1091646/when-the-arguments-of-two-roots-of-a-quadratic-equation-are-equal

Comment: @randomgirl: $x_1 = 1$ and $x_2 = i$ is a valid example which the roots have the same absolute value *but* they are not of the form $a\pm bi$. Note that $d$ and $g^2$ are complex.

Answer (score 0):

(I assume we already knew $e^{i\phi}=\cos\phi+i\sin\phi$ here.)

Let the two roots be $x_1 = Re^{i\theta_1}$ and $x_2 = Re^{i\theta_2}$. Then we get:

\begin{align}
x_1 + x_2 &= R(e^{i\theta_1} + e^{i\theta_2}) = -d \\
x_1x_2 &= R^2 e^{i(\theta_1 + \theta_2)} = g^2
\end{align}

Thus $g = \pm R e^{i(\theta_1 + \theta_2)/2}$. The sign will not affect whether $d/g$ is real so we just choose "−" here.

Then,

\begin{align}
\frac dg &= \frac{e^{i\theta_1} + e^{i\theta_2}}{e^{i(\theta_1+\theta_2)/2}} \\
&= (e^{i\theta_1} + e^{i\theta_2})(e^{-i(\theta_1+\theta_2)/2)}) \\
&= e^{i(\theta_1 - \theta_2)/2} + e^{i(\theta_2 - \theta_1)/2} \\
&= 2\cos\frac{\theta_1-\theta_2}2 \in \mathbb R.
\end{align}

Comment: How do we know that x1 + x2 = -d and x1x2 = g^2?

Comment: @JHNV: Expanding $(x-x_1)(x-x_2)=x^2+dx+g^2=0$. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas#Example.